# web.config rewrite rule in Child folder

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

I've a simple site with a web.config file for rewriting URL's

for instance, navigating to www.domain.com/story will show the page at www.domain.com/story.php

I've added a child folder with a copy of the site with a Chinese translation to www.domain.com/zh

I can access the story page at www.domain.com/zh/story.php but not www.domain.com/zh/story

How do I need to configure my web.config file? I've tried copying the web.config file to the /zh folder but this doesn't work, I've also tried copying and changing my match URL from ^story to ^zh/story but this also doesn't have the desired effect. Can someone suggest what is going on please?

Here is my existing web.config in the web root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>

            <rule name="Rewrite to story.php">
              <match url="^story" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="story.php" />
            </rule>

          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Right now you are rewriting only if the url starts with `story`. What is the full scenario here?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had a chance to try myself, but try something like this:

```
<rule name="Rewrite to story.php">
    <match url="^zh/story" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="zh/story.php" />
</rule>
```